# Exlude part of string from filtering in tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using Mottie's Tablesorter plug-in for jQuery and I have a question:

**is there any simple way to exclude part of the cell from filtering?**

I have something like this:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════╗
║ Row # ║    Value    ║
╠═══════╬═════════════╣
║ row_1 ║ 31 (22 + 9) ║
║ row_2 ║ 22 (18 + 4) ║
╚═══════╩═════════════╝
```

I filter **value** column, but I have to filter only that first value (i.e. 31, 22). When I filter this example for "22", the first row stays too, because it contains 22 in brackets. I don't want it.

Also, I can't split it into two cells. Something like *<span data-filter="disable">* would be so handy here, but I haven't found anything about this.

Comment: have you thought about writing a custom sorter function? just ignore everything between brackets (or your own custom markup), or just use a custom `textExtraction` function for the `value` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `textExtraction` function to only grab the value from outside the parentheses ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/3471/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        textExtraction: {
            1: function (node) {
                return $(node).text().split(' (')[0];
            }
        },
        widgets: ['filter', 'zebra']
    });
});
```

Then to only filter parsed data, add the "filter-parsed" class name to the header:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Row #</th>
            <th class="filter-parsed">Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```